# Nodejs override or add another return response

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a variable, FirstName and LastName, I want to add it to the return response,

note the FirstName and LastName are not present/available on table Student.

```
let result = await Student.get(id)
let FirstName = "Paul"
let LastName = "Richard"

results = {
  ...result,
  FirstName: params.body.FirstName,
  LastName: params.body.LastName
}
```

current result

```
{
  0:{
     "Teacher": "adasfsafag",
     "Subject": "asdafdfhd",
  },
  "FirstName": "Paul",
  "LastName": "Richard"
}
```

what i want is

```
{
  "Teacher": "adasfsafag",
  "Subject": "asdafdfhd",
  "FirstName": "Paul",
  "LastName": "Richard"
}
```

when I didnt add the FirstName and LastName in the respone

this is the result

```
{
  "data": {
     "School":{
         "Teacher": "adasfsafag",
         "Subject": "asdafdfhd"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you confirm if `result` is an Array?

Comment: yes the result is Array

Comment: `{"data" : { "School": { "Teacher" : ..., "Subject": ... }}};` ---> this does not seem like an array to me. If this is the value of result, then `data.School.Teacher` and `data.School.Subject` will contain the values you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to spread the nested node `School` this way:

```js
const result = {
  "data": {
     "School":{
         "Teacher": "adasfsafag",
         "Subject": "asdafdfhd",
      }
  }
};
const FirstName = "Paul";
const LastName = "Richard";

results = { ...result.data.School, FirstName, LastName };

console.log(results);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Destructure the first element of the array.  You might want some bounds checking before doing this...

```
if (result.length) {
 results = {
   ...result[0],
   FirstName: params.body.FirstName,
   LastName: params.body.LastName
 }
// or 
 results2 = {
   Teacher:result[0].Teacher,
   Subject:result[0].Subject,
   FirstName: params.body.FirstName,
   LastName: params.body.LastName
 }
}
```

Comment: I received this error `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Comment: Then your result holds objects other than data.

Comment: I added another option to solution